# Quartz scheduled job being triggered after a long delay with 15 minutes delay

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have a non-concurrent quartz job running on 6 application server instances. A high level responsibility of the job is to walk through a DB table and process and update which ever row is expired. Now I see a behavior of the job which is not understandable.

I have a configuration by which the job should be triggered after 15 minutes, but as the span of a single run can be multiple days, each of this trigger after 15 minutes should be suppressed by a lock already acquired by running job instance.

So, the ideal behavior is, job starts running on one of the 6 server instances, it completes a single DB table iteration in let us say 3 days. Meanwhile, quartz is trying to push in another job every minutes, but as lock is already acquired, it should not. After 3 days when the first job run finishes quartz scheduler should succeed in starting another job, within <= 15 minutes of the first run endtime.

But, in reality I see a behavior, where the the job has run for some days and has not run for some of the days. some time this gap is as long as 8-10 days. I am unable to explain this scenario.

The closest theory I can think of, is that it might be the case that during a particular job run, the server instance got killed(due to deployment/redeployment), because of which the quartz did not get a chance to remove shared lock. So, all the attempts of acquiring a lock for next job run keep on failing till the orphan lock is not expired by an expiry date. The moment it got expired, a new job kicks in.

My question here is, what could be the possible explanations to this, and more importantly, how to debug it? Any leads to Quartz Lock management documentation for non-concurrent jobs can helpful.

I use `DisallowConcurrentExecution` annotation for non-concurrency.

Comment: You can look at QRTZ_* tables (like QRTZ_TRIGGERS and QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS) to get more info on your job.  Also look at your logs to see whether you see trigger misfire. Do post additional information like qrtz config parameter and what you see in the log.

Comment: without looking at the code and logs, it is impossible to tell what is happening

Comment: @Ravi Can you give more insight on how `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` works and how does quartz maintain distributed locking across instances?